# Resize Greek letter in an equation

Tags: math-mode, letters

Is there a way to resize Greek letters if they are in an equation?

This is the code of the equation (for example):

```
\begin{equation}
G_{\mathds{1}\sigma}={\epsilon}({\sigma})\delta_{\mathds{1}},\pi_{\ell}\sigma=1\Rightarrow\qquad\epsilon{\sigma}=1\qquad\pi(\sigma)=\mathds{1}\\
\end{equation}
```

I would like to make only the `\epsilon` and the `\delta` larger.

Comment: I just ask why you would want to use a larger letter, because I can't imagine a usage in which it wouldn't look awful. My apologies for the inappropriate tone of my previous message.

Comment: Becouse I am writing  a very important scientific document and I need it, becouse it's not so visible if it remains small.

Comment: It needs to be only as visible as it is by default. I hope I'll never have to copy-edit your work :-)

Comment: Changing the size of selected symbols and characters risks making your document look as professional as a ransom note, I.e., utterly unprofessional. Is this a risk worth taking?

Comment: I don't know why do I have to explain to some people why I would like this special modification of my document. It was just a special request, and I was waiting for the answers which can solve my problem maybe. 
But If you so curious I can send you a picture of the equation how it is unvisible and chaotic even so I tried \varepsilon.

Comment: @HajnalkaKorka - You are not being asked to, let alone compelled to, explain anything. You are merely getting well-intended words of caution about the professional advisability of your stated objective. What you do with your document and your career is, of course, your business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\mathlarger` from the [`relsize`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package, but as Heiko has mentioned in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240672/15874), it looks quite odd:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  G_{\mathds{1}\sigma} = \mathlarger\epsilon(\sigma)\mathlarger\delta_{\mathds{1}}, \enskip
  \pi_{\ell}\sigma = 1
  \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad
  \mathlarger\epsilon\sigma = 1, \enskip
  \pi(\sigma) = \mathds{1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

It you want `\epsilon` and `\delta` to be larger throughout the entire document and don't have to use them for other stuff in the document, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{relsize}

\let\origEpsilon\epsilon
\renewcommand*\epsilon{\mathlarger\origEpsilon}
\let\origDelta\delta
\renewcommand*\delta{\mathlarger\origDelta}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  G_{\mathds{1}\sigma} = \epsilon(\sigma)\delta_{\mathds{1}}, \enskip
  \pi_{\ell}\sigma = 1
  \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad
  \epsilon\sigma = 1, \enskip
  \pi(\sigma) = \mathds{1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The size of the lowercase Greek letters epsilon and delta is correct.
Enlarging them would look quite odd in comparison to the other characters.
For instance, the lowercase delta would be larger than an uppercase letter.

Maybe you do not like the form of the epsilon, there is an alternative `\varepsilon`, which appears larger. Also a small horizontal space can be added between the closing brace and the `\delta` to make clear, `\delta` starts the new factor. The following example also adds some space after the comma, because it separates equations and sets the same space around `\Rightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  G_{\mathds{1}\sigma} =
  \varepsilon(\sigma)\,\delta_{\mathds{1}},\;
  \pi_{\ell} \sigma = 1
  \quad\Rightarrow\quad
  \varepsilon{\sigma} = 1,\;
  \pi(\sigma) = \mathds{1}\\
\end{equation}
\[ \epsilon \mbox{ vs.\ } \varepsilon \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]